# Wampserver Orange - PHP_curl.dll

Tags: php, dll, curl, wamp

My Wampserver is orange and won't change.

When I go onto the Apache error log i get

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.4.3 
/    ext/php_curl.dll' - The application has failed to start because its 
side-by-side configuration is incorrect. Please see the application event log or]
 use the command-linesxstrace.exe tool for more detail.\r\n in Unknown on line 0
```

I understand that this is a fairly common problem relating to the php_curl.dll. However I have tried many solutions and none work. I have tried both php 5.4.3 dll fixes(anindya's blog) and replaced the dll file in \wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\ext.  Curl is ticked and active in the php.ini file.     extension_dir = "c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.4.3/ext/" ( Where the curl is located)

php_curl.dll  libeay32.dll  ssleay32.dll have been copied from c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.13/ext/ into C:\Windows\system32.

Is there anything else that could be causing this error I am merely trying to install Zend and its just been so complicated trying to get it to work.

I am running Wamp 2.2 on windows 7 64 bit. I have restarted WAMP after making changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1st. You close WAMP if you are using.

2nd. You'll %WAMP% / bin / php / (tuversion)

3rd. Edit php.ini -> Find the word curl, uncomment remove the semicolon) extension = php_curl.dll and guards

4th. Now you %WAMP% /bin/apache/(your_version)/bin

5th. You edit the php.ini -> Find the word curl, same uncomment (remove the semicolon) extension = php_curl.dll and guards

6th. Lift the WAMP again and ready.

Should work this..

Answer (score 2):

The 64bit version of WAMP distributed with unusable curl extension.

Get one here instead (scroll down near end of post, titled **Fixed curl extensions**):

http://www.anindya.com/php-5-4-3-and-php-5-3-13-x64-64-bit-for-windows/

Answer (score 0):

I am using WAMP for my 64 bit machine and faced this issue.
I tried the above specified solutions but still was facing the same error. The problem I found was with the php_curl.dll file inside my php/php-version/ext folder.

I replaced it with another php_curl.dll file downloaded from here

https://www.filesanywhere.com/fs/v.aspx?v=8a726a8a596273b7a6af

Replacing the original file with this file solved my issue and curl_init() function started working fine.
Before copying, stop your wamp server and then restart it again.
I hope this helps.